# Size of Python Executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable

I have a somewhat complex Python file that is literally 14K, when saved as a .py file. I used the following technique to convert it into an executable:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile MyCode.py
```

Now, the executable is 309MB. I deployed it to a VM, ran it, and it works fine.  However, I'm questioning the bloat; does this make any sense?

Comment: When you package it into an `.exe`, it also has to include the standard library and any other imports you have, along with `python.exe` to actually run python.

Comment: You could try setting up a `venv` and only having the necessary installs, but otherwise it's difficult to reduce that file size.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I still think it is quite excessive, and very inefficient, for the file to grow over 20,000x in size.  I guess, it is what it is.  Thanks for the insight everyone!